# Правильный план для Cross DB views

Tags: sql-server, view

На уровне представления собираю данные из нескольких БД с одинаковой структурой:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TestCrossView] 
AS
(
SELECT
      ID,
      Result.SText,
      Result.DbName
FROM  ( SELECT
              CAST(0 AS INT) AS ID,
              CAST('' AS NVARCHAR (100)) AS [SText],
              CAST('' AS sysname) AS [DbName]
        UNION 
        SELECT
              [id],
              [SText],
              [DbName] AS [DbName]
        FROM  [DbTestCheckCross1]..TableSession
        UNION 
        SELECT
              [id],
              [SText],
              [DbName] AS [DbName]
        FROM   [DbTestCheckCross2]..TableSession
        UNION 
        SELECT
              [id],
              [SText],
              [DbName] AS [DbName]
        FROM   [DbTestCheckCross3]..TableSession ) AS Result
);
```

Далее выполняю запрос с фильтрацией по имени БД:

```
DECLARE @DbName sysname = N'DbTestCheckCross1'

SELECT TOP (1000) tcv.[ID]
      ,tcv.[SText]
      ,tcv.[DbName]
  FROM [DbTestCheckCrossMain].[dbo].[TestCrossView] tcv
  WHERE DbName = @DbName
```

В [плане запроса](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1jztWTXD) вижу сканы по всем базам внутри представления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если такой запрос выполняется долго, то запрос которому требуется блокировка схемы, будет ожидать выполнения этого запроса.

Проблему решает хинт `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` или указание константы в фильтре.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли другой способ заставить движок отсечь ненужные БД?
Секционирование не предлагать ;)

Comment: Да, присутствует, и к сожалению выполняется. Проверено на большой конфигурации. Если такой запрос выполяется долго, то запрос которому требуется блокировка схемы, будет ожидать выполнения этого запроса.

Comment: Да это тестовый стенд, вот план: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1jztWTXD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операторы сканирования в плане запроса располагаются за фильтрами, в свойствах которых определены *startup expression*, например:

[image: Startup_Expression_Predicate]

Это означает, что в run-time сканирование будет выполняться только если соответствующий фильтр его пропустит (startup-предикат будет иметь значение True).

Из четырёх веток, объединяемых в Concatenation, фактически лишь одна (выделенная) поставляет данные при указанном значении переменной

[image: Plan_highlighted]

Только у выделенного Table Scan число выполнений ненулевое

[image: Number_of_Executions_1]

у остальных операторов сканирования оно равно нулю

[image: Number_of_Executions_0]

Есть, однако, нюанс. Перед началом выполнения запроса execution engine установит *Sch-S* блокировки (*schema stability*) на все таблицы, участвующие в запросе (независимо от того, будет ли происходить чтение данных из конкретной таблицы, или не будет). Соответственно `ALTER`, `TRUNCATE` и всё, для чего требуется *Sch-M* блокировка (*schema modification*), становятся невозможны на таблицах до окончания запроса.

Если нужно этого по-возможности избегать, то вариант с константой, в данном случае, видимо самый лучший (либо то же самое с помощью динамического запроса). Вариант с `RECOMPILE` менее желателен, но он может быть не таким уж и злом, если компиляция запроса малозатратна относительно выполнения.

Следует отметить, что *Sch-S* блокировки устанавливаются также и на время компиляции. С константой или `RECOMPILE`, когда ненужная таблица полностью выпадает из плана, время нежелательной блокировки будет естественно меньше.

Порой невозможно угодить всем требованиям, приходится выбирать разумный компромисс, исходя из того, что важнее.